# Mi aplicacion pierde la fuente tipografica al ejecutarla en otra pc, QT creator, c++

Tags: c++, qt

tengo creada una aplicacion con Qt creator en la cual utilize una fuente que no es estandar de window. Despues de hacerle deploy y ejecutarla en otra pc la fuente tipográfica de todo el texto cambia y esto daña bastante en lo que a visual se refiere a la aplicacion

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que `windeployqt.exe` detecte la fuente que estoy usando en la aplicacion y la incluya dentro del deploy, y asi se vea en otras pcs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos posibilidades:

- Adjuntas la fuente como recurso (la añades al fichero .qrc). Si haces esto tendrás que indicar que la fuente se encuentra como recurso incrustado, lo cual cambia ligeramente la forma de localizarla:

  ```
  int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/mifuentepersonalizada.ttf");
  QString family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
  QFont miFuente(family);
  ```
- Instalas la fuente en los equipos donde vayas a ejecutar la aplicación. Esto lo puedes hacer a mano, con un *script* dentro de tu aplicación o creando un instalador de la aplicación. En este caso la carga de la fuente no cambia respecto a tu código original.

---

Edito:

Pasos para cargar la fuente:

**añadir la fuente a qt**

Lo primero es asegurarse de que qt carga la fuente. Para ello basta con añadir esta línea:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(“:/fonts/fuente-regular.ttf”);
```

Donde `fonts/mi_fuente.ttf` es la ruta del recurso.

Esta línea se puede poner, por ejemplo, en el constructor de la ventana principal o en algún punto de la inicialización.

**usar la fuente**

Para usar la fuente desde la hoja de estilos podemos usar lo siguiente:

```
font: 18pt 'fuente';
```

Comment: ese codigo de tu comentario donde va? en el main,?? en el cpp de la UI?? y despues que tenga incrustada la fuente en la aplicacion mediante el .qrc como, por ejemplo , a un label le pongo esa fuente??? siempre lo hago mediante el stylesheet

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR he editado la respuesta. Espero que el nuevo contenido resuelva tus dudas

Comment: gracias, ahora si, funciona perfecto